Getting "Unhandled endpoint" error while trying test scenarios on appium for iOS and Timeout error for Android
I am trying to run my test scenarios on iOS as well as on Android but all the tests are failing on the login step. I will share screenshots of my error as well -
iOS
Android
I am running the appium server GUI in the background and my appium version is 1.22.3, also I have tried upgrading my version and running it on 2.5.1 and 2.5.4 but the error still persists.
P.S. If you think I have missed anything and something else is required please ask for it.
Thank you !
